# pm-suspend fails to wake up

Tags: debian, suspend

I use `pm-suspend` on Debian 7.5. Most of the time everything works perfect, but sometimes it fails to wake up. The fans spin up, even the hard disk shows activity, but there is only a blank screen. After some time, I can see a strange mouse pointer on the screen, which looks like this:

[image: mouse poiinter]

When this happens, I can't change to another console or do anything. Only shutting down power and rebooting helps. The log (`/var/log/pm-suspend`) indicates a successful wakeup. I think this is not an X server error since I cannot even use my keyboard to change to a tty. Anyway, I use `xorg 7.7`.

**EDIT** - hardware:

- AMD FX-8120 CPU
- Sapphire Radeon HD 6850 VGA, 1st screen connected via HDMI, 2nd via DVI
- ASUS M5A97 PRO motherboard with UEFI firmware (up to date, but the latest update is from October, 2012)

Comment: This is a hardware-specific bug (either a hardware/firmware bug or a driver bug). What exact computer model do you have?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, might be. I updated the question with info on my hardware.